# Extract all releases from GIT repository

Tags: version-control, linux

I would like to examine an existing Git repository and extract all defined releases into a subfolder.

For example, if application A had 26 releases, my bash script would extract all 26 versions into subfolders such as:

A/(folder) for each of the defined releases

The preferred language is bash

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I figured out my own question:

```
    git checkout $tag
  git --work-tree=$outputLoc checkout HEAD -- .
```

Comment: It is good that you found your answer, and thank you for self-posting it. This might have got a better response on Stack Overflow. Although your plan might be to do some data analysis on code changes - which potentially could be on topic here - use of Bash and command-line options for Git are not really data science topics.